# Font size in `whitespace:pre` elements

Tags: html, css

I am writing a site and I don't want to make it complex.

Fortunately it looks just fine on mobile (per my taste), but there is only one issue:
code in divs which are `whitespace:pre` is too small. It seems like font outside of the page gets set in some units that keep it constant size to the viewer and it gets bigger on mobile. But pre keeps it constant width, and it stays small.

Is there some magic setting that I need to add to `whitespace:pre` that would make font size act the same way as without it?

Minimal example:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
    div {
      max-width: 860px;
    }
    pre {
      max-width: 860px;
    }
  </style>

    <body style="font-size: 15px">
        <div>
“Well, Prince, so Genoa and Lucca are now just family estates of the Buonapartes. But I warn you, if you don’t tell me that this means war, if you still try to defend the infamies and horrors perpetrated by that Antichrist—I really believe he is Antichrist—I will have nothing more to do with you and you are no longer my friend, no longer my ‘faithful slave,’ as you call yourself! But how do you do? I see I have frightened you—sit down and tell me all the news.”
        </div>
        <pre style="max-width:860px;">
            Text inside of pre.
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

## Mobile:

[image: Mobile]

Comment: Please add a reproducible code or link with a demo to understand the issue

Comment: Yes, good point, sorry about that. Trying to make a simple example now.

Comment: I have added example, please take a look.

Comment: Add a meta viewport tag.

Comment: @gre_gor meta viewport tag breaks other places of the page. Font outside of pre is just fine, I'd like to achieve that in pre too.

Comment: How about `pre {font-family: unset; font-size: inherit}` ?

Answer (score 0):

This might work if you add font-size in  **pre** tag as well that will set the font size and will appear the same for both devices.

For example:

```
    <style>
    div {
      max-width: 860px;
    }
    pre {
      max-width: 860px;
      font-size:12px // or whatever you want
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: Nope, it didn't help. Same sizing problem.